# Posting client side data to server through Ajax Call or Http Post is better?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, http

I want to post the value from few Controls to server side upon a button click. After this I don't want to redirect my page to else where. I just wanted to display the 'Submitted Successfully' message without a page reload. Which one will be more efficient if I have to submit a large amount of data including images?

Comment: If you're (that) serious about performance, you really ought to measure both...

Comment: How can I do that????

Comment: Implement both, then measure their respective performance.  If you implement the easiest one first, and it has acceptable performance, then perhaps you're done..?

Comment: Ajax is just HTTP request and could very well be a POST request.  Theyd be one and the same.  I would use ajax though if you want to avoid page refresh